# I have a function that only allows users to see their own files, I want to disable this for admin/editors but struggling to get it to work

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the following code to let users only access their own media files, which works great;

```
add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'show_current_user_attachments', 10, 1 );
function show_current_user_attachments( $query = array() ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if( $user_id ) {
        $query['author'] = $user_id;
    }
    return $query;
}
```

The trouble is, I want to do this for those with a user role lower than editor (So editors/admins only can see all the media files).

I have tried wrapping my function in this code but it didn't seem to work as intended, it just hangs whilst trying to load the media files (for any user), here's a screenshot of what it looks like.

[image: Media library hanging for all users.]

Does anyone have any suggestions for solving this issue?

Thanks, Harry.